# Parse Cloud function which every hour checks all rows in Parse.com table and if needed updates a column

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I need to deploy a function which every hour checks all rows in a table in Parse.com. I have there columns ValidFrom(Date), ValidTo(Date) and Active(bool). So it passes all rows and for a row where DateTime.UtcNow < ValidTo && DateTime.UtcNow >= ValidFrom it updates Active value to True otherwise it updates Active to False.
I don't know where to start.. Can you point me to the right direction please?

Comment: I don't understand why someone give a minus point for this question a gave no answer and no comment. What's wrong on this question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a background job in parse and schedule it to work every hour by adding it to  the jobs schedule in the Web Console.

check this link 
http://blog.parse.com/2013/09/04/introducing-background-jobs/

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud, this is exactly what I need. With a little querying I can do that job.